# Removing Element from Document Flow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a `[type=checkbox]` to record the user input for a custom dropdown menu that I created. I'm also using it for the `required` functionality in browsers too.

[image]

The issue I'm running into, however, is that the element seems to need at least `1px` of `height` in order to trigger the browser warning message when a user tries to submit the form without filling out that part. This is an issue because the dropdown menu has a `height` of `auto`, so as soon as the browser warning message is displayed, it shifts everything up so that there is a `1px` gap at the bottom.

[image]

***Notably, the content only shifts if or once the warning message is displayed.***

I know that I can fix this by `positioning` the element `absolutely` with JS, but I'm trying to use as little JS as possible. Hence I've given the container a `position: relative`, and positioned the element so that it always displays at the bottom center of the container element like all of the other fields.

```
#dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

#subject {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

As I stated above, I've already tried giving it a height of `0`, but by doing this the warning message does not trigger. I've also tried a couple different `display` values (and I will be going through the rest of them once I finish positing this). I've also tried applying `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` to the last option in the list. None of this stuff works.

```js
const
  option = document.querySelector('#option')

document.querySelector('#dropdown').addEventListener('click', function(){
  option.style.maxHeight = option.scrollHeight + 'px'
})
```

```css
#dropdown {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid red 3px;
}

#label {
  padding: 50px;
}

#option {
  max-height: 0;
  transition:
    .5s max-height;
}

#option:hover {
  background: skyblue;
}

#checkbox {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px; /* added extra pixels to emphasize the issue */
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div id='dropdown'>
    <div id='label'>Subject</div>
    <div id='option'>Last Option</div>
    <input id='checkbox' type='checkbox' required />
  </div>
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

**Does anybody have any ideas how I might be able to do this with CSS alone?**

**Is it even possible since the container has a `height` of `auto`?**

Comment: Post HTML as well please and read about [mcve]

Comment: @zer00ne the HTML is far too extensive

Comment: Just a enough so that it can be tested accurately. Say like it would be important to know if the checkbox is before or after a label, etc.

Comment: @zer00ne im creating an MVP right now

Comment: @zer00ne all done. can u take a look?

Comment: Sure thing.....

Comment: @zer00ne i changed the demo slightly to emphasize the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `position: static` with `display: block` seems to work for me. This does make the tool tip appear at the top of the div, however:

```js
const option = document.getElementById('option')

document.getElementById('dropdown').addEventListener('click', function(){
  option.style.maxHeight = option.scrollHeight + 'px'
})
```

```css
#dropdown {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid red 3px;
}

#label {
  padding: 50px;
}

#option {
  max-height: 0;
  transition:
    .5s max-height;
}

#option:hover {
  background: skyblue;
}

#checkbox {
    /* display: block; */
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 11px; */
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #0f0f0f;
    width: 5px;
    left: 50%;
}

#checkbox {

}
```

```html
<form>
  <div id='dropdown'>
    <div id='label'>Subject</div>
    <div id='option'>Last Option</div>
    <input id='checkbox' type='checkbox' required />
  </div>
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

I have found that using `top: 100%;` is the issue here.

Comment: `position: static; display: block` have no effect or do not address the issue. you can move the element anywhere but the bottom of the container, and the issue does not exist. the issue only exists when the you put the `checkbox` at the bottom of the container because the `height` of the container is `auto`. anyways, i need the `checkbox` to be bottom center of the container so that the warning message is bottom center like all of the other warning messages.

Comment: I see, I didn't realise that's what you wanted. I'll look into doing that now

Comment: its all good. i figured u had misunderstood the question. ill might be back for a minute or two in a couple hours but tomorrow morning if not

Comment: @Anthony It seems `position: absolute` does seem to work?

Comment: @Anthony It turns out top: 100%; was the culprit :P

Comment: judging by your demo, i think you mayve figured it out. but thats weird because i tried using `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` and it didnt work for me. so maybe the trick is to make it `position: static: bottom: 0;`?  ill get back to tomo morning when i wake up

Comment: i just tested it quickly. thats so fucking bizarre. now its working locally for me. i tried `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` immediately after i posted the question and it didnt work. so weird

Comment: @Anthony, No, that was my previous solution. You had used `top: 100%;`, which im guessing the 100% had something to do with it, because even with `background-color: black;`, you could only see a clear (white) space. And yes, absolute should do the trick, no need for static.

Comment: i know i had `top: 100%` in my initial demo, but immediately after i posted the question i tried `bottom: 0` instead and it didnt work. go look at my edit. i edited the question shortly after posting it, mentioning that i had tried it and that it didnt work

Comment: my 2nd edit to the question, i added it to the near the very bottom of my question

Comment: maybe i forgot to refresh the page after or didnt save the document before testing

Comment: @Anthony I see. At least it works now :P Absolute position should always work.

Comment: yeah well it does make sense why `top` wouldnt work and `bottom` does cuz the `height: auto`

Answer (score 0):

#### Major Changes

- `div#option` is now `label.option[for='checkbox']`. If a label has a `[for]` attribute with its value of a checkbox or radio #id, they will be associated with one another so if a user clicks one the other is clicked as well. This association works as long as both are on the same page no matter how close, far apart, nested, or not nested.
- `label[for='checkbox']` has been assigned `display:block` because it replaced a div.
- `#checkbox` is now entirely out of `div,dropdown` and assigned `z-index:-1` and positioned with `vh` and `vw` units so it's position will responsively adjust to any window resizing. The form has it's background color set explicitly so that the checkbox is totally concealed but as far as the browser is concerned it's visible and so `required` will always work.

#### Minor Changes

- Most of the #id were changed to classes isn't required, I just did it because I don't like #ids.
- Also removed some other unnecessary styles that are no longer needed for at least the provided code.

```js
const option = document.querySelector('.option');

document.querySelector('.dropdown').addEventListener('click', function() {
  option.style.maxHeight = option.scrollHeight + 'px';

});
```

```css
form {
  background: #fff
}

.dropdown {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.label {
  display: block;
  padding: 50px;
}

.option {
  display: block;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.5s
}

.option:hover {
  background: skyblue;
}

#checkbox {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50vw;
  bottom: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<form>

  <div class='dropdown'>

    <label class='label'>Subject</label>

    <label for='checkbox' class='option'>Last Option</label>
  </div>

  <input type='submit'>
  <input id='checkbox' type='checkbox' required>
</form>
```

Comment: it doesnt address the issue tho? the warning message doesnt show up when you try to submit the form without selecting the checkbox?

Comment: When the `.option` is opened the checkbox has been checked. Click anywhere within the red bordered box and the checkbox is checked.. Or did you want the `.option` to be the checkbox?

Comment: Ok, updated. `.option` is now associated to checkbox. No extra JS.

Comment: thats more what i was looking for, but why `top: 10vh;`? an explicit percentage height other than `0` or `100` is going to cause issues. turns out, even though i tested `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` and it didnt work at the time for some reason (e.g. maybe i didnt save the changes or refresh the page), that `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` is exactly what im looking for.